# Delete pubished and unpublished posts with wp_delete_post?

Tags: posts

There is a function that removes all the posts from a given post type but it doesn't remove items that status is "draft".  How would it catch the draft items too?

```
   function remove_all_kba_data(){
        //remove articles
        $articles = get_posts( array( 'post_type' => 'kb_kba', 'posts_per_page' => -1) );
        foreach( $articles as $article ) {
            //delete post, bypass trash
            wp_delete_post( $article->ID, true);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`get_posts()` can receive an argument describing which post status to operate. I would say something like this:

```
function remove_all_kba_data(){
    //remove articles
    $articles = get_posts( 
        [ 
            'post_type' => 'kb_kba', 
            'posts_per_page' => -1, 
            'post_status' => [ 'published', 'draft' ]
        ] 
    );
    foreach( $articles as $article ) {
        //delete post, bypass trash
        wp_delete_post( $article->ID, true);
    }
}
```

Comment: for my site the post_status needed to be 'publish' rather than 'published'